# What is the big O memory usage of maps in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering what the big O memory usage of maps in C++ (like how arrays use O(n) memory). In the [C++ documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/), it says

> Constant for the empty constructors (1), and for the move constructors (4) (unless alloc is different from x's allocator).
> For all other cases, linear in the distance between the iterators (copy constructions) if the elements are already sorted according to the same criterion. For unsorted sequences, linearithmic (N*logN) in that distance (sorting,copy constructions).

but I'm having a hard time understanding what this means. Does this mean that maps use O(n*log(n)) memory? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is [much better documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: What makes you think that this passage is talking about complexity in terms of memory *usage* instead of insertion time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are N nodes, so the memory usage is `O(N)`.

For accuracy, its' `N * sizeof(std::map<KeyType, ValueType>::node_type)`, and may plus one more node for the sentinel root node. Note that `node_type` is added since c++17.

`node_type` is larger than `value_type`, since it contains `value_type` and some more info(red-black tree colors and left-right child pointers for most [implementations](https://www.walletfox.com/course/mapcustomkeySource/map.png))

For the size [comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/5harz7e3Y):

```
    std::cout << sizeof(std::map<int, int>::value_type) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(std::map<int, int>::node_type) << std::endl;
```

We may get 8 and 24. So map costs several times more memory than a vector of pairs, especially for small data types like int. Though they both have O(N) space complexity.

---

Maps are good, then how to save memory for small maps(And may also improve the performance since we may reduce the calling for memory allocation)? There are some existed solutions, we use a [vector based map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx):

> Boost.Container flat_[multi]map/set containers are ordered-vector
> based associative containers based on Austern's and Alexandrescu's
> guidelines. These ordered vector containers have also benefited
> recently with the addition of move semantics to C++, speeding up
> insertion and erasure times considerably. Flat associative containers
> have the following attributes

Comment: Well yes, but there are some pitfalls to consider. First of all node_type is only exposed since C++ 17. Second of all there is no guarantee that the map is implemented as rb-tree even though most, if not all, implementations do so.